# Duda sobre excepciones en patron mvc propio

Tags: php, mvc, excepciones, try-catch

Hace poco, me dio la gana de crear un framework propio utilizando el patrón MVC para probar mis habilidades. (Aclaración, está desarrollado en php y se utiliza mysql para las BD)
Mi framework tiene la siguiente arquitectura:

[image: Disculpen por el dibujo a mano]

En síntesis:

1. Desde un index.php instancio de la clase controladorDeRutas y le envio el mensaje controladorDeRutas->comenzar(); que inicia todo el proceso.
2. El controlador de rutas lo que hace es capturar la URI, procesarla y determinar que controlador se va a utilizar y que método de esa clase se va a llamar.
3. Si el controlador precisa información de la base de datos, se la solicita al modelo, y éste se conecta con la base y realiza consultas a traves de la clase conexión.
4. Por último, el controlador envía la información que solicito a la vista correspondiente.
   PD: si el controlador no precisa información de la BD, simplemente llamará a la vista.

El problema que tengo es con las excepciones. Lo que hice fue (aunque no creo que este bien) utilizar un try/catch en el index (archivo que empieza la ejecución de mi aplicación) para capturar cualquier excepción que se lance más adelante (o sea en controlador.php, modelo.php, conexion.php, vista.php, etc)
Simplificando detalles, sería algo así:

**index.php**

```
$ruta = new controladorDeRutas();
try{
    $ruta->comenzar();
}
catch(Excepcion404 $e){
    Vista::crearVista("nombreDeLaVistaAMostrar", $e);
}
catch(ExcepcionConexionABaseDeDatos $e){
    Vista::crearVista("nombreDeLaVistaAMostrar", $e);
}
...etc
```

Es por eso que si en alguno de los archivos se lanza un error, lo capturo en el iniciador de mi proceso (index.php).
El tema es que no se si esto este del todo bien. Se me había ocurrido, por otra parte, lanzar excepciones y capturarlas en los demás archivos, en vez de concentrar todo en el index. Ejemplo:

conexion.php

```
...código...
if($conexion->errno){
    throw new ExcepcionConexionABaseDeDatos;
}
...código...
```

modelo.php

```
...código...
public function buscarTodosLosUsuarios(){
    $conexion = new Conexion();
    ...código...
}
...código...
```

controlador.php

```
public function mostrarUsuarios(){
   $modelo = new Modelo();
   try{
       $modelo->buscarTodosLosUsuarios();
       Vista::crearVista("nombreDeLaVistaAMostrar");
   }catch($e){
       Vista::crearVista("nombreDeLaVistaAMostrar", $e);
   }
}
```

No sé si se entendió. En el primer caso capturo todas las excepciones en el index con un solo try/catch. En el segundo caso debería hacer un try/catch por cada excepcion que ocurra, para capturarla en el controlador y mostrar la vista corresponiente. 
En definitiva (resumen):

- ¿Conviene capturar todas las excepciones lanzadas en el index?
- ¿Conviene capturar las excepciones en cada caso particular desde el controlador?
- ¿Qué opción optarían ustedes?¿Se les ocurre alguna otra idea?

Si leíste hasta acá, gracias por tomarte la molestia de hacerlo.
Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: Sólo para asegurarme... el primer recuadro pone "Controlador de Rutas", ¿verdad?

Comment: Si, en el primer recuadro es el "ControladorDeRutas.php", si es eso a lo que te referías @SJuan76

Comment: las excepciones son por niveles dentro de un try/catch puedes colocar una excepcion y si quieres salir a la exepcion mas grandes puedes hacerlo mediante **throw new Exception('el mensaje que te de la gana');** ,un pequeño ejemplo de dos niveles nivel 1 es el index nivel 2 es un simple error de query como controlastes el error en el nivel 2 puedes colocar la linea ejemplo que te envie y asi pasaria al nivel 1

Answer (score 0):

No conviene captura las excepciones en el index porque no sabrías siquiera cuantas existirían, tendrías que hacer cada página a prueba de todo.  Cada controlador debería encarar los posibles errores que sucedieran en la lógica que maneja.

En tu diseño deberías incluir un patrón que te permita manejar las excepciones de un grupo, ejemplo: todo lo referente a modelos.  Puedes buscar patrones tipo "[observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)" para ponerte un ejemplo.